# Boring javascript calling: why a non-desirable js function has been called?

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an aspx page with a button that calls another page in a different window, through javascript:

```
function assuntos() {
        window.open("pg_assuntos.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=480");
    }
```

in the page's Onload event, I have the code:

```
bot_cadastrar.Attributes.Add("onclick", "assuntos()")
```

When I click the button, all gonna be right. But everytime I update a fild that execute a query, the "onclick" event seems to be raised or function seems to be executed, because the window is opened. I also have another code in the onload event for starting a stopwatch javascript function:

VB CODE:

```
Dim script = "<script language = javascript>" & _
                   "window.setTimeout('ShowTime()', 1000);</script>"

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, "iniciar", script)
```

ASPX CODE (javascript):

```
function ShowTime() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var dif = dt - dtIn;
    var tim = new Date();
    tim.setHours(0, 0, 0, dif);
    document.getElementById("<%= cmp_hora.ClientID %>").value = dt.toLocaleTimeString();
    document.getElementById("<%= cmp_tempo.ClientID %>").value = tim.toLocaleTimeString();
    window.setTimeout("ShowTime()", 1000);
}
```

Why the function is starting for itself? I'm fed up whith these popups!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you need to return false on the javascript call on assuntos function

```
    function assuntos() { 
window.open("pg_assuntos.aspx", "List", "scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=480"); 
    return false;
    }
```

Comment: good tip, but the window stills showing. When the form is loaded, the window is not oppened, but when I execute a query typing [Enter] in a textbox the function is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem: bot_cadastrar was setted to "submit" behavior. Then, every time the form was submited, the "click" event for the button was raised. I guess that the first answer helped to. Thanks.